# Return all the rows even the joined table has empty results

Tags: php, sql, join, rows, multiple-columns

In my table 1 I have something like this

```
name     |  age  
George      42
Bob         30
Ken         23
```

In my table 2, I have something like this, this is where i store votes for each person.

```
name    |   votes  | 
George       1
Ken          1
George       1
George       1
Ken          1
```

My goal is to combine the 2 tables, and return all the rows in table 1 even it doesn't exist in table 2.

Desire results:

```
name     |  age   |  total_votes
George      42       3
Bob         30       0
Ken         23       2
```

But instead I get:

```
name     |  age   |  total_votes
George      42       3
Ken         23       2
```

I have tried something like this

```
SELECT `table_1`.*, coalesce(COUNT(`table_2`.votes), 0) AS total_votes
FROM `table_1`
LEFT JOIN `table_2`
ON `table_1`.name = `table_2`.name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of these:
    1) Use Right Join instead of current Left Join.
Or
    2) Exchange table1 and table2 places in your join expression, like:
    FROM `table_2`
    LEFT JOIN `table_1`

Comment: I did that too, same results

Comment: Did you do just one of them or two? if you do both of number 1 & 2, you'll get same result, but if you do just one of them i think it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This works in MS Access , I think this will work on your's too just convert the query to SQL:

```
SELECT Table1.name, First(Table1.age) AS age, Count(Table2.Votes) AS totalVotes 
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.name = Table2.name
GROUP BY Table1.name;
```

Left Join table1 to table2 so that all entry from table1 , even if its is corresponding data is null, will be included. GROUP BY your query by name so that votes will be counted by name .